# C# and ASP.net saving html into a string or a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, file-io

I'm new to ASP and I was wondering if there is a way to save the source of the web-page into a string variable or a .txt file given a website address using C# or ASP.net with C#.

If its possible, example code and information on what libraries to reference would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class for that:

To a string variable:

```
string result;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    result = wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

To a file:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
wc.DownloadFile("http://stackoverflow.com", @"C:\test\test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

At a basic high level.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

An example can be found on the link posted above.